# How to define two dimensional array variable in Z3py

Tags: python, arrays, z3py

I want to define a two-dimensional boolean array in Z3py. Actually, I want to access the array indices using other integer variables, e.g.,  A[x][3], where x is an integer variable whose value is decided by the SMT-solver in runtime.

If I define the two-dimensional array as follows:
A = [ [ Bool("a_%s_%s" % (i, j)) for j in range(5) ] for i in range(5) ]
then, I get "TypeError: object cannot be interpreted as an index" on adding the constraint like (A[x][3]==True).

I checked that for a z3 array defined as  A = Array('A',IntSort(),IntSort()), I can access the array indices using other integer variable (e.g., A[x]). Now, I want the same for two-dimensional array.

Please help me in this regard.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can model nested arrays like this:

```
A  = Array('A', IntSort(), ArraySort(IntSort(), BoolSort()))
```

That is, the first index is an integer, which indexes into another array from integers to booleans.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: and how get element? for example all element with this same value